# Can glscissor clip multiple area?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

i am stucked in a problem and looking for help here.
I want to clip the screen, only part of the screen can be displayed. I used glscissor and met a problem. It seems like glscissor can only difine ONE rectangle on the screen, but i hava to display multiple areas at the same time, can anyone tell me how to do?
thanks.
forgive my poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrissor is limited to one rectangle, indeed. If you want to clip to multiple rectangles, you can either draw everything once per clip-rectangle, or use the stencil buffer to mask the different areas.